# How do I locate or generate the .NET source files for AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to get the .NET source code, not the TypeScript source code. I've googled for quite a while and tried to dig through the main source code repository for documentation on this. Not finding answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist. CDK is written in TypeScript and then converted to other languages at release using their [`jsii` tool](https://github.com/aws/jsii).

You can generate the .NET code using jsii yourself if that's what you're after. [The CDK github documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#pack) explains how to do this:

> Packing involves generating CDK code in the various target languages and packaging them up to be published to their respective package managers. Once in a while, these will need to be generated either to test the experience of a new feature, or reproduce a packaging failure.

> To package a specific module, say the @aws-cdk/aws-ec2 module:

```sh
$ cd <root-of-cdk-repo>
$ docker run --rm --net=host -it -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD jsii/superchain
docker$ cd packages/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2
docker$ ../../../scripts/foreach.sh --up yarn run package
docker$ exit
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for. Just couldn't find.